# When slide the slider to some hours of slotLabelInterval. The events should changed in the view

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Is it Events should change the position in the fullcalendaer view based on slotLabelInterval (slide the slider ) ?

Is  it slotLabelInterval is only divide the slotduration?

When slide the slider to some hours it will effect the slotLabelInterval.Then the events should also  move based on slotLabelInterval time period in the fullcalendar.

```js
var calendar = null;
    var datetime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    var slotLabel = '';

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: 'UTC',
            slotMinTime: '06:00',
            slotMaxTime: '19:00',
            slotDuration: '00:30',
            slotLabelInterval: slotLabel,
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
            height: 650,
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
            },
            slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false
            },
            allDay: false,
            editable: true,
            resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Manager',
            initialDate: today,
            businessHours: [ 
                {
                    daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                    startTime: '07:00', 
                    endTime: '18:00' 
                }

            ],

            resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
            resources: [{
                id: 'a',
                title: 'Employee 1'
            },
            {
                id: 'b',
                title: 'Employee 2'
            },
            {
                id: 'c',
                title: 'Employee 3'
            },
            {
                id: 'd',
                title: 'Employee 4'
            }
            ],
            events: [{
                title: 'Event 1',
                start: today + 'T07:30:00',
                end: today + 'T12:00:00',
                resourceId: 'a'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 2',
                start: today + 'T09:30:00',
                end: today + 'T14:00:00',
                resourceId: 'b'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 3',
                start: today + 'T08:30:00',
                end: today + 'T12:00:00',
                resourceId: 'c'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 4',
                start: today + 'T10:30:00',
                end: today + 'T14:00:00',
                resourceId: 'd'
            }
            ]
        });
        calendar.render();
    });

    var value = 0;
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("displayValue");
    var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
    var hourOutput = $("#hours")[0];
    var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
    hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
    $('.slider').change(function () {
        debugger;
        var hours = Math.floor(slider.value / 60);
        hourOutput.innerHTML = hours;
        slotLabel = hours + ':' + '00';
        if (calendar) {
            calendar.setOption('slotLabelInterval', slotLabel);
            
        }
    });
```

```css
a {
            color: var(--bs-link-color);
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #storlekslider {
            width: 30%;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <h3 id="displayValue">
            <span id="hours" style="display:none;">min</span> 
        </h3>
        <label style="font-size:medium">Duartion</label>
        <input type="range" min="60" max="480" step="0.5" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" style="height:9px;">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Be aware you still have `code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0` and `code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1` references in your code. Make sure they're both pointing at the same version!

Comment: `Is it slotLabelInterval is only divide the slotduration`...yes, that's correct.

Comment: `Then the events should also move based on slotLabelInterval time period`...I'm not entirely sure what you are expecting? slotLabelInterval just changes how often a label is put onto a slot - it's purely a visual alteration. I don't know what changes to events you would want to make based on that? Can you give a specific example based on the events in your example code, please? e.g. give an example of an alteration to the slider, and then tell us exactly how you think each event should change based on that.

Comment: Hello @ADyson sorry for delay reply. My expectation is when slide the slider(slotLabelInterval) events should change the sizes(maximize and minimize ) based on time period

Comment: Like I said, I don't really understand exactly how that would work in practice - please [edit] your question to provide specific examples as I requested. The slotLabelInterval merely changes the spacing of the _display_ of the times on the calendar. I don't understand logically how it could make any sense for it to also alter any of the events just because the user changed it